# Making profile page unique by adding unique ID in URL. But how?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a social network script using PHP/MySQL. Everything is working fine. Homepage,Profile, edit profile etc. But the Profile page has URL - http://www.localhost/socialnetwork/profile.php.

I have 5 dummy users and When profile is accessed using their usernames/password. The same URL can be seen on browser.

But I want something like -

URL - http://www.localhost/socialnetwork/profile.php?u=testuser.

Where 'u' can be a unique user Id in database. How to implement it ? Here's my code -

```
<?php  
include("includes/session.php");
include("includes/database.php");
include("includes/user.php");
include("includes/functions.php");
if(!$session->is_logged_in()) { redirect_to("login.php");}
?>

 <?php
$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
// - Here's What I have added  - But nothing changes. The URL is same.
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$uid =   $_GET['id']; 

}

$sql    = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id' LIMIT 1"; 
$result = $database->query($sql);
while($record = $database->fetch_array($result)){

$fname      = $record['fname'];
$lname      = $record['lname'];
$email      = $record['email'];
$sex        = $record['sex'];
$password   = $record['password'];
$phone      = $record['phone'];
$birthday   = $record['birthday'];
$display    = $record['dp'];
$bio        = $record['bio'];
 }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you're fully opened up for SQL injections (unless you escape `id` before putting it into your session). You need to use prepared statements and bind variables or at least escape your variables before pasting them into a query.

Comment: I know, Its just the raw code. Once it works all right, I'll fix security issues. But As you understand my question - Its not just implementing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `$_GET['u']` to read out the url
2. Have in your DbTable a column username whith a UNIQUE INDEX
3. Use a SQL-query combining both to read the user-profile

Answer (score 0):

**BEFORE PROFILE.PHP**

When the user "foo" (a dummy username) logins, he is redirected to the page

```
http://www.localhost/socialnetwork/profile.php?u=foo
```

Great! But how do we do it? The redirection is made in PHP, with something like:

```
header('location: /socialnetwork/profile.php?u=' . $theusername_just_logged);
```

The [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function basically redirects to another page. After that function is called, you will land into the page

```
http://www.localhost/socialnetwork/profile.php?u=foo
```

**INTO PROFILE.PHP**

Inside the file profile.php, then, you retrieve the username through the variable $_GET. In this particular case, $_GET['u'] will contain the username, which is "foo". [Here more info about $_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Once you retrieved the username, you can query the database to get all the infos of that user and build the page basing on them!

This way, basing on the $_GET['u'] you will always get a different page! Please consider to make a proper error page if the username doesn't exists in the database

Hope it helped

Comment: I got the idea. I made some changes. But No results. The page still shows same URL.Should I upload my code ?

Answer (score 0):

add this in your while loop

```
$id=$record['id'];
```

then make a link in your while loop
like this

```
echo '<p>
<a href="the url of your profile page.php?id='$id'">

'.$fname.'

    </a></p>';
```

this will echo  out all the names in your db,and add uniqueness to them.
And when your on your profile page you can get the id of that particular user using

```
echo $_GET[id'];
```